# Structuring multiple objects within an array

Tags: javascript

3a. Create a const variable named jurassicParkMovies and set the value to an array of two objects. Use the following keys and values for each object in the array: Key value pairs for the 1st object are (one: "Jurassic Park", two: "The Lost World: Jurassic Park", and three: "Jurassic Park III"). Key value pairs for the 2nd object are (four: "Jurassic World", five: "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom", and "Jurassic World: Dominion"). (NOTE: I would suggest using some copy and paste on this one)
3b. Create a function called seeJPMovies. Having only the following inside the opening and closing curly brackets of the seeJPMovies function (See below), have all six movie names display in the terminal/console when the function is run (HINT: There are at least two ways this can be done)...

```
console.log(one);
 console.log(two);
 console.log(three);
 console.log(four);
 console.log(five);
 console.log(six);
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and the FAQ [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `seeJPMovies` expect an object as an `argument` (with the expected keys set `one, ..., six`), then merge & spread the source array when you call the function:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    one: "Jurassic Park",
    two: "The Lost World: Jurassic Park",
    three: "Jurassic Park III",
  },
  {
    four: "Jurassic World",
    five: "Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom",
    six: "Jurassic World: Dominion",
  }
]

const seeJPMovies = ({ one, two, three, four, five, six }) => {
  console.log(one);
  console.log(two);
  console.log(three);
  console.log(four);
  console.log(five);
  console.log(six);
}

seeJPMovies({ ...arr.reduce((a, c) => ({ ...a, ...c }), {}) })
```